# Сломался компилятор(или нет)

Tags: c

При исполнении файла с `strlen()` происходит ошибка сегментации.

Все методы перепробовал. Объявлял массивы, присваивал им значения, объявлял переменные(не массивы) и присваивал им значения.

Ну, а теперь вопрос: Это у меня руки не из того места растут, или всё таки make сломался?

Пример кода:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int g = 123;
int main()
{
 printf("%d", strlen(g));
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: приведите полный пример вашего кода

Answer (score 2, accepted):

функция `strlen()` возвращает длину строки, она принимает на вход константный указатель на массив символов, её прототип:

```
size_t strlen( const char * string );
```

вы передаёте `int g = 123;` это неправильное использование функции, правильное использование будет таким

```
char str[10] = "string";
printf("%d", strlen(str)); //выведет 6
```

Comment: Спасибо) Только сейчас заметил, что написал %s, а не %d)

Comment: ан нет. проблемы ещё и с вот этой нарко командой:  
strcpy(d, strlen((f)));

Comment: а что именно? `strtok` первым аргументом принимает НЕ константантный указатель, т.к. эта функция изменит str, потом `strtok` возвращает опять же НЕ константный указатель, который не подходит для strlen. И тут возникает вопрос, а что вы вообще хотите сделать?

Comment: я правил) он не хочет присваивать переменной д длинну строки ф)

Comment: так а что такое d и что такое f? Какие у них типы?

Comment: массивы char[1000]

Comment: f - strtok, d - пустая

Comment: тогда получается, что d это константный указатель на массив, а по прототипу strcpy первым аргументом принимает обычный (не константный) указатель

Comment: а как тогда исправить это???

Comment: во первых я не понимаю, зачем записывать число в строку d, когда можно сказать `int d = strlen(f);`, но если вам нужно именно так, как раньше, то d должен быть `char* d;`

Comment: спасибо, всё заработало), только есть одно но: у меня в строке 31 символ. А он пишет 37, почему?

Comment: концом строки считается символ `\0` видимо строка содержит скрытые символы

Comment: ...Ясно, но вот что с этим делать?)

Comment: зависит от кода, иногда можно поставить 0 самостоятельно в строку

Comment: всмысле склеить?

Comment: нет, вычислить конец значащих символов и написать что-то вроде str[n] = 0

Comment: аааа, ясно, спасибо)